# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from tutorial import views
from accounts.form import Registrationform,EditProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm,PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
    name="jay"
    args={'myName':name}

    return render(request,'accounts/home.html',args)
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Registrationform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('please fill all the fields and make sure new password must be match')
    else:
        form = Registrationform()
        args={'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/reg_form.html',args)

def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user' : request.user}
    return render(request,'accounts/profile.html',args)

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account/profile')
    else:
        form  =  EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args)

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST,user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect('/account/profile')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("password doest not match,go back and try again")
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        args = {'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/change_password.html',args)
```

and form.py is

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from django.forms import RegistrationForm,EditProfileForm

class Registrationform(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        )
    def save(self,commit=True):
        user=super(Registrationform,self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name= self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email=self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    #template_name = '/something/else'
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'password'
         )
```

and urls.py

```
#python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
from django.contrib import admin
from .import views
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib.auth.views import login,logout,password_reset,password_reset_done,password_reset_confirm,password_reset_complete
#from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.home),
    url(r'^login/$',login,{'template_name' : 'accounts/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$',logout,{'template_name' : 'accounts/logout.html'}),
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$',views.view_profile,name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$',views.edit_profile,name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password/$',views.change_password,name='change_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/$',password_reset,name='reset_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$',password_reset_done,name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    password_reset_confirm,name='password_reset_confirm' ),
    url(r'^reset-password-complete/$',password_reset_complete,name='password_reset_complete'),


]
```

So when i enter url -" http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/profile/edit/ " its give me  error

> "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'"

What is the mistake ?what i did wrong here ? and django gives this line error

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py in
>   inner, line 205.

what should i do to solve this error ?

Comment: Make sure you are logged in before navigating to edit profile page.

Answer (score 4):

You are not logged in and trying to modify profile. To prevent such kind of error, add [`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) validation to your view. If user is not authenticated, you can redirect him to `login` page with [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut function:

```
def edit_profile(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:  
     if request.method=="POST":
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account/profile')
     else:
        form  =  EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form' : form}
        return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args) 
  else:
     return redirect('/login/')
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use `login_required` decorator. It will check whether user logged in or not without coding it explicitly.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):

     if request.method=="POST":
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account/profile')
     else:
        form  =  EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
     args = {'form' : form}
     return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args)
```