# django login form returns 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-authentication

I am working on a django web app. In this web app, I have a login page. But when I use the click the login button, I get the following error message

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I tried looking for this online and found these links in StackOverflow. **[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619927/django-login-attributeerror-anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-meta)** and **[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323218/anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-meta)**. But the answers provided in these links do not seem to be working for me.

This is my code so far
views.py

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        user = form.get_user()
        login(request, user)

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('global:homepage')

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
```

login.html

```
<form class="" action="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <p>
        <div class="form-group">
            {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help-block"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p style="color: red">{{ error|add_class:'text-danger' }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg mt-5">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong or what the error message means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `form.is_valid()` before retrieving and logging in the user as they may not have provided the correct credentials

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('global:homepage')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I am such an idiot. Just noticed it now. thanks a lot